# wso2 api manager have xss issue

Tags: wso2, xss, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API MANAGER VERSION 1.10.0

Sample API published with script description in publisher portal

[image]

and i open the api detail in store portal

[image]

setting carbon.xml is below

```
<XSSPreventionConfig>
     <Enabled>true</Enabled>
     <Rule>allow</Rule>
     <!--Patterns>
         <Pattern></Pattern>
     </Patterns-->
</XSSPreventionConfig>
```

How can I solve it with setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download security patches for APIM 1.10.0 from [here](http://wso2.com/security-patch-releases/#api-manager). This is already fixed in them.

Comment: Here is a part of the fixes. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/1565/files
Other fixes are in the same code base. Please note APIM 2.0.0 has more such security fixes.